# Converting hash to array of hashes order preserved?

Tags: ruby

I have a hash `h`:

```
h = {145=>1, 137=>2, 34=>3}
```

I want to convert it into an array of hashes of the form:

```
[{cid:145, qty:1}, {cid:137, qty:2}, {cid:34, qty:3}]
```

My first attempt a solution works for this example:

```
h.keys.zip(h.values).map { |cid, qty| {cid:cid, qty:qty} }
```

Evaluates to

```
[{:cid=>145, :qty=>1}, {:cid=>137, :qty=>2}, {:cid=>34, :qty=>3}]
```

My worry is that `h.keys` and `h.values` won't always align, since hashes aren't necessarily ordered.

How can I solve this problem with the guarantee that the keys of `h` will be paired with their corresponding values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h = {145=>1, 137=>2, 34=>3}
h.map!{ |k, v| {:cid =>k, :qty => v} }
```

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about wanting JSON.

Comment: Sorry guys, I had troubles to update fast my answer. Now the code will works. The way, using map the pairs of keys and values will keep the correct relation.

Comment: `map!` isn't defined on hashes. You want `map`.